Distribution of N Car Platoons
Source: Feller's "Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications Volume II" Section I Problem 10. It seems related to this question on MSE, except that one is about the expectation (I did not find any answer explicitly describing the distribution).

Cars start successively at the origin and travel along the right $x$-axis without passing. Each car keeps a constant speed, but we consider the speeds $v_1,v_2,\dots$ as a sample from a sequence of independent random variables with a common continuous distribution function $F$. When a car reaches a slower car it is compelled to trail it at the same speed. In this way platoons will form. Show that the probability of a given car being trailed by exactly $n$ cars tends to $[n(n+1)]^{-1}$ independently of the distribution $F$ and the times of departure.

Attempt: Let's fix the speed of a car so $V_i=v_i$. Then the probability of exactly $n$ cars trailing, conditioned on the speed of the first car, is $(1-F(v_i))^nF(v_i)/(n+1)$ and we can get the probability by integrating over all the speeds of the first car:
$$ \int_\Omega \frac{(1-F(v_i))^nF(v_i)}{n+1}f(v_i)dv_i=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}$$
Question: It seems I must have messed up somewhere along the way, but not entirely sure where. Perhaps the probability of $n$ cars trailing is somehow $F(1-F)^{n-1}$ (if I work backwards trying to arrive at Feller's answer) or I didn't integrate properly?

The probability that at least $n$ cars follow a given one is the probability that the given car's speed is less than all previous $n$ cars.  For iid speeds following a continuous distribution, this is $\frac1{n+1}$.
The probability that exactly $n$ cars follow is then the relative complement
$$\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2} = \frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Ah silly me - it's just like the example he provided: $P{N\geq n}-P{N\geq n+1}$. Is there a way to do this without taking the difference of the tail distributions?

@MarkO Explicitly, possibly?  You just want the $n+2$ cars ending with the given car to start with the minimum and end with the second-smallest.  You probably can evaluate this directly, but most methods I can imagine still involve a relative complement somewhere.

The issue I had with that approach (arranging the order statistics) is that I wasn't sure how that guarantees exactly $n$ trailing cars because the second smallest in the group of $n+2$ cars could occur at the end but that's not to say subsequent cars do not come by with faster speeds?

Given a sample $v_i$ we need to find the probability that there are exactly $n$ samples with $v > v_i$ after $v_i$. This will ensure they catch up to $v_i$ and trail behind it. The $\left(n+1\right)^\mathrm{th}$ sample must then have $v < v_i$ to ensure only $n$ cars are trailing.
Since $F(v_i)$ is the cumulative probibility of $v \le v_i$, the associated probability of the sequence of $n$ trailing cars is $(1-F(v_i))^nF(v_i)$. The probability of sampling $v_i$ is $f(v_i) = F^\prime(v_i)$ and the total probilibty can then be obtained by integrating over all speeds (samples),
$$
P = \int_0^\infty (1-F(v_i))^nF(v_i)f(v_i) dv_i
$$
We can simplify the integral by substituting $x = F(v_i)$ where $x = 0$ at $v_i = 0$ and $x = 1$ as $v_i\rightarrow\infty$.
$$
P = \int_0^1 (1-x)^n x dx
$$
This evaluates to the Beta function $B(2, n+1)$. And since $2$, $n+1$ are positive integers,
$$
P = \frac{n!}{(n+2)!} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$$

I arrived at the same answer, but wasn't sure if there needed to be an extra $n+1$ on the bottom to account for the fact that I need the car $\leq v_i$ to be at the end (i.e. it's not just any grouping of $n+1$ cars)
